# Private Github Repositories with Envoy

Tags: deployment, laravel-envoy

Anybody has any problems deploying with Laravel's envoy when using private Github repos?

When manually cloning my repo from the production server, the ssh key seems to be accessible but when using Envoy, I always get a "Permission denied (publickey) error.

[image: Envoy problem]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because the ssh key on your remote server requires a password.

If you change the `Envoy.blade.php` to perform some other task you should be able to establish whether you are connecting to your remote correctly.

```
@servers(['web' => 'user@domain.com'])

@task('deploy')
    cd /path/to/site
    git status
@endtask
```

Should return something like:

```
[user@domain.com]: On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

If you are connecting using a Mac or Linux you probably don't have to enter your password because your terminal is using `ssh-agent` which silently handles your authentication.

[Wikipedia article on ssh-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent)

When connecting over ssh, ssh-agent isn't running and the script is being prompted for a password which is where it is failing.

To get around this you could to generate a new key on the remote machine that doesn't use a password.

If you want to restrict the ssh key to a single repository on GitHub have a look at [deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the **-A** (as per the man page it - Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file) in you ssh string.

You will also need add your ssh key for agent forwarding (on the machine which can access the git remote which I assume be your localhost)

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/your_private_key
```

Something like this

```
@servers(['web' => '-A user@domain.com'])

@task('deploy')
 cd /path/to/site
 git status
@endtask
```

Git remote commands should now work.